# Dynamic route ASP.NET Core 5 MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-5.0

I need to perform the following functionality.

When a user logs in the user session stores the company name. What I need to do is that any url of the controller is low in the name of the company.

For example: assuming that the company name is mycompany (obtained from the user session) and I have the `UsersController` and `FilesController`, how can I get the urls to look like:

```
 1. /mycompany/users
 2. /mycompany/users/myid
 3. /mycompany/files
 4. /mycompany/files/myid
```

Thank you very much for the help you can give me.

Comment: How would your api differentiate between /mycompany/* vs /someotherroute/* ?

Comment: Use [URL Rewriting Middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/url-rewriting?view=aspnetcore-5.0#method-based-rule) and implement your own rule logic in a [method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/url-rewriting?view=aspnetcore-5.0#method-based-rule)